# cannot connect to beaglebone black via ethernet or ssh

Tags: ssh, ethernet, beagleboneblack

I cannot connect to my beaglebone black via ssh or usb,

I could connect via ssh/ethernet before I edited a file, and rebooted.

I thnink the file I changed was uEnv.txt and I think I commented out the line about HDMI

Any ideas? do i just need to reinstall the debian OS? via the memory card?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If it really was the uEnv.tx-file you don't need to reflash your img.
You can edit the uEnv.txt file again (easly with the plugged USB and explorer). If you comment things out in this file, the driver can't work properly. If you can tell me your img version (that's very usefull if you write it by every question down) I can show you the unmodified uEnv file.
You can easy also google that file.

An alternative way is to reflash the img. Recommendable for new BBB / Linux users. The img an guide is available at [beaglebone.org](http://beagleboard.org)

I hope I answered your question, otherwise write again!

Comment: As I said, I couldnt connect via USB, in the end I had to re flash, which was fun! took 3 or 4 goes to get it right.